# How do I access an NTFS storage partition?

Tags: 11.04, partitioning, ntfs, gparted

I upgraded to 11.4 beta (absolutely fantastic) on Asus EEE pc 1005ha.  I have a NTFS storage parition (/dev/sda4) visible by gparted.  However, I cannot access it via Ubuntu.  Any tips or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda4 "some folder path"`

to see if it mounts or not. See that package `ntfs-3g` is installed. If you wan't it to be mounted all the time you can use something like `ntfs-config` or enter mount point manually on `/etc/fstab`. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) for more information.

Since it is visible in gparted it should be visible in Disk Utility as well. Try mounting from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

What sagarchalise suggested is also a way to mount the partition, but that would not mount the partition automatically upon each login (until you edit your `fstab` file), to mount the partition automatically, following are the steps you need to perform:

**NOTE**: Following steps are intentionally written to be performed via GUI so that casual users can do it without any fear of Terminal. The Ubuntu help page does have same steps, but they are Terminal friendly.

- Make sure the partition you want to auto-mount is **NOT** mounted currently.

  - Press Alt+F2 (Run Dialog) and write `gksu nautilus`.
  - Navigate to directory `media` from the `Filesystem` from the Nautilus sidepane.
  - Create a new directory and name it whatever you want, but avoid the use of any space or symbols in the name, a simple alpha-numeric name is recommended. Eg; **Drive1**.
  - Close Nautilus.
- You can skip this step if already know on which device the partition is located (`/dev/sda4` in your case) but those who don't know it can use following steps to identify the partitions.

  - Open Terminal from using short-cut Ctrl+Alt+T.
  - Enter command `sudo blkid`
  - the command will print the devices on which each partition is located, i.e. `/dev/sdaX` or `/dev/sdbX` where `X` will be a number unique for each partition, you'll also get other information like UID of each partition, its filesystem, etc.
  - Note the details and close Terminal.
- Now again, open Run Dialog and enter `gksu gedit /etc/fstab`.

  - This will open the `fstab` file in Text Editor with ROOT privileges.
  - Now append the following line at the end of the file, replacing `sdaX` with `sda4` or anything else what you noted from Terminal when entering `sudo blkid`. And also replace `MountPoint` with the **NAME** of directory you created in `/media` directory for the partition you want to auto-mount.

    `/dev/sdaX /media/MountPoint ntfs-3g rw,defaults 0 0`
  - Now, save the file and close Text Editor.
  - Now, open Terminal and enter `sudo mount -a`.
  - Open Nautilus and check if the partition is now mounted.

Now everytime you'll start Ubuntu, your partition will be auto-mounted (the way it does in Windows) with full read-write access. You can perform same steps to auto-mount all the partitions you have, but, keeping different names for mount points and appending their respective details in `fstab` file.

I wonder if a any GUI utility exists for Ubuntu that can do exactly the same without touching Terminal or open `fstab` manually.