# Live USB and Windows - Using Chroot

Tags: chroot

On Linux you can use the commands below on a Ubuntu live USB to get root access onto the hard drive. Does anyone know if this method works for a Windows hard drive? My guess is that it should, but I've not tried it.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Comment: You dont gain root access to a disk drive - you gain root priviliges to the operating system. As long as the disks are not encrypted you can access all data on all disk as long as you have operting system root priviliges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access an NTFS storage partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35325/how-do-i-access-an-ntfs-storage-partition)

Answer (score -1):

Yes this should work, providing that the windows hard drive is called sda1.

Comment: Well I tried it and I got the error below. Weirdly enough I could just mount the drive onto /mnt and then cd into it. It kinda makes me question what the purpose of using chroot is. It's very confusing. My guess is that code is not executed on the drive, it would be executed on the live USB. It makes me wonder if it's possible to just execute a file on the drive instead?

    chroot: failed to run command /bin/bash